# C# error's question as type or namespace issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, game-engine, vuforia

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;  
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float movementSpeed =100f;

    private float verticalDirection;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    private Animator animator;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
      public bool IsMoving()
    {
        return rb.velocity.magnitude > 0.1f;
    }
    
    void Awake()
    {
        rb=GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        animator = GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        verticalDirection=Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        verticalDirection=Mathf.Clamp(verticalDirection,0,1);

        animator.SetFloat("Speed",verticalDirection);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity=Vector3.forward*verticalDirection*movementSpeed*Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    }
}

Error1:
Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(4,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MonoBehaviour' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error2:
Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(10,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Rigidbody' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error3: 
Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(12,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Animator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error4:
Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(12,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Animator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error5:
Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(6,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SerializeFieldAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error6:
Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(6,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SerializeField' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error7:
Assets\Scripts\Robot.cs(20,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PlayMovement' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


It is my other code
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Diagnostics;  
//using System.Runtime.Serialization;
//using UnityEngine.UI;
//using System.web.Helpers;

enum RobotStates {Counting,Inspecting}
public class Robot : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float startInspectionTime = 2f;
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource jingleSource;
    private float currentInspectionTime;

    private RobotStates currentState = RobotStates.Counting;

    private Animator animator;

    private PlayMovement player;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        player=FindObjectType<PlayerMovement>();
        animator=GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();

        currentInspectionTime = startInspectionTime;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        StateMachine();
    }

    private void StateMachine()
    {
        switch(currentState)
        {
            case RobotStates.Counting:
                Count();
                break;
            case RobotStates.Inspecting:
                Inspect();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    private void Count()
    {
        if (!jingleSource.isPlaying){
            animator.SetTrigger("Look");
            currentState=RobotStates.Inspecting;
        }
    }

    private void Inspect()
    {
        if(currentInspectionTime>0)
        {
            currentInspectionTime -=Time.deltaTime;
        
            if (player.IsMoving())
            {
                Destroy(player.gameObject);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            currentInspectionTime=startInspectionTime;
            animator.SetTrigger("Look");

            jingleSource.Play();
            currentState=RobotStates.Counting;
        }


    }

}
```

I have 7 error about CS0246. I used all namespace whatever I can use but it does not work. I checked the briket and semicolon all of them but i am not sure why i get error. I used
**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video; 
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

**
Those namespace but it does not work please help me............
**Please note the parenthesis which are causing the issue I have labelled Error Parethesis however I am not entirely sure these are causing the overall issue.

Comment: Pay utmost attention to the error messages. Do **not** gloss over error messages. Which source code file are the error messages referring to? No you didn't use all the namespaces you claim to use, when considering your PlayerMovement class. Look at your code in the question: Which namespaces have been imported when the compiler reaches the declaration of your PlayerMovement class?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a space between the using System.Diagnostics; and the monobehaviour and also make sure it has the same name as the script file you created.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the error messages:

> Error2: Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(10,13): error CS0246: The
> type or namespace name 'Rigidbody' could not be found (are you missing
> a using directive or an assembly reference?)

`RigidBody` requires a reference to `UnityEngine.PhysicsModule`

> Error3:  Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(12,13): error CS0246: The
> type or namespace name 'Animator' could not be found (are you missing
> a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> Error4: Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(12,13): error CS0246: The
> type or namespace name 'Animator' could not be found (are you missing
> a using directive or an assembly reference?)

`Animator` requires a reference to `UnityEngine.AnimationModule`

> Error5: Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(6,6): error CS0246: The type
> or namespace name 'SerializeFieldAttribute' could not be found (are
> you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Error6:
> Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(6,6): error CS0246: The type or
> namespace name 'SerializeField' could not be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)

`SerializeField` requires a `using` reference to `UnityEngine.CoreModule`

> Error7: Assets\Scripts\Robot.cs(20,13): error CS0246: The type or
> namespace name 'PlayMovement' could not be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)

Should this be `PlayerMovement` rather than `PlayMovement`?